# ¿Como puedo corregir el conflicto con claves foraneas en laravel?

Tags: laravel-10

> Ya intente de varias formas y no logro corregirlo:

```
   INFO  Running migrations.  

  2024_02_20_115327_empleado ......................................................................................... 70ms FAIL

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `inventario`.`empleado` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `empleado` add constraint `empleado_sexo_id_foreign` foreign key (`sexo_id`) references `sexo` (`id_sexo`))

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioE\InventarioGUI\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:829
    825▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    826▕                 );
    827▕             }
    828▕
  ➜ 829▕             throw new QueryException(
    830▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    831▕             );
    832▕         }
    833▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioE\InventarioGUI\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:587
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `inventario`.`empleado` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\InventarioE\InventarioGUI\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:587
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

> Tomando en cuenta que tengo claves únicas, que se tomaran como claves foráneas de mi tabla empelados
> pero me crea el error, a la hora de hacer la migración de la tabla, otro detalle extra que tengo es >que si me crea la tabla, pero me marca ese error de las claves foráneas, las demás tablas que tengo creadas, no tengo ningún detalle de creación, pero necesito poder encontrar corrección a esto.